# Trying to embed a video in a Views Header

Tags: views, files

I am trying to embed a video in the header of Drupal 7 View. I have the header text format set to full HTML. The full HTML text format is set to: (X = checked)

- _ Limit allowed HTML tags
- _ Display any HTML as plain text
- X Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)
- X Convert URLs into links

The code below is what we used to embed the video in our Drupal 6 site but it was in an article not a views header. No video is showing up in the header and view source shows that the code is getting stripped out.

```
<div id="mainFlash">
<embed id="mainFlash" width="550" height="440" quality="high" name="mainFlash" src="http://www.oursite.com/main-video-en.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</div>
```

Is it possible to embed the video? Do I need to use the <object> tag instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Full HTML' format in Drupal 7 by default still strips out some of your tags, check your format settings under Administer » Configuration » Content authoring » Text format, or /admin/config/content/formats/ and you'll see that for the Full HTML format, you're limited to the following tags:

```
<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd>
```

You can either add an object, embed tag here to make these work for this input format or you can add a separate input format that has no restrictions. The choice will really depend on what kind of site you are running and who else might have access to this format. If I were letting users use the 'Full HTML' format for adding comments, content, I would definitely want to restrict the tags they use and allow only admins access to an unfiltered format.

Comment: Thanks. I thought if I unchecked "Limit allowed HTML tags" it would allow everything.